# In context of "Illumeo on 3rd party PACS" project, what the following components mean: preproc, prefetch, prepstore, retrieve

Tags: integration

In context of "Illumeo on 3rd party PACS" project we have a few workflows (available in [MSTeams](https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/pdf/viewer/teams/https%3A~2F~2Fshare.philips.com~2Fsites~2FIllumeoStandaloneIntegrationForum~2FShared%20Documents~2FGeneral~2FWorkflow_sequences_20181016.pdf?threadId=19%3Abec50ea05f494c70a834e0610181430c%40thread.skype&baseUrl=https%3A~2F~2Fshare.philips.com~2Fsites~2FIllumeoStandaloneIntegrationForum&fileId=D5194380-F295-406C-8438-9775833000A5&ctx=files&viewerAction=view) or in [TFS](http://tfsemea1.ta.philips.com:8080/tfs/TPC_Region11/riinnovation/_wiki?pagePath=%2FNPD-Tech%2FBusiness-Programs%2FEnabling-Stand-Alone-Illumeo%2FWorkflow-Sequences)) where there are some components which purpose is not clear, particularly: preproc, prefetch, prepstore, retrieve.
What are they for?

Answer (score 0):

According to Walco,

**Preproc**: proprietary component that pre-processes DICOM images needed for smooth display in Illumeo

**Prefetch**: our forConnect stuff

**Prepstore**: stores the results of preprocessing as described in Preproc description above. Basically an S3 object store suffices for this

**Retrieve**: the part of forConnect that goes out to fetch DICOM. Doesn’t really add much to the understanding of the component though...